# Combination help on algorithm to create augmented factorial design

Tags: r, algorithm, combinations

I am trying to create an algorithm that will create all possible combinations of adding two runs in a 2^k factorial design. I have seen many example of combination out there but none of them really address this specific problem. The result of this algorithm should be a matrix of k number of columns and (2^k choose 1) + (2^k choose 2) + 1  number of rows to give the correct number of 2 combinations. So for a 2^2 design we will have 2 columns and 11 rows (4 + 6 + 1) I designed this matrix below just to show how it should look like. Where each pair of rows (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) etc is  supposed to be different different (I know it isn't right now ). This does not need to be super efficient or in a specific language but would prefer R, I just need to figure out what kind of approach can be used to do this

```
Run   A   B
 1   -1  -1
 2   -1  -1
 3    1  -1
 4    1  -1
 5   -1   1
 6   -1   1
 7    1   1
 8    1   1
 9   -1  -1
10   -1   1
11    1   1
```

Comment: Why are rows 1 & 2 separated? Wouldn't it be easier/clearer if each row had four columns?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion David. If each row had four columns then the table would represent a four factor factorial (A, B, C, D). However , If there is a way of making sure the elements in those four columns are different in all rows, I could just do some matrix operations to put it in the right format.

Comment: In your example, rows 6 and 7 are identical to rows 10 and 11.

Comment: Hello @SvenHohenstein I realized that question had a lot of mistakes. And trying to make the tables by hand was confusing. I will change it a bit and post a way I found on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying to do this in the most effective ways (Only one more row than the total number of combinations) and failing. I decided to go with an approach that will produce all the combinations in the format where rows (1&2),(3&4), etc are two different combinations. Here is the code in R if anyone is interested

```
numFactors <- 2
org <- gen.factorial(2,numFactors)
orgRow <- nrow(org)
x <- c(seq(1,orgRow))
z <- (x*2)
numARow <- sum(z) ##Double the total combinations
aug <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = numARow, ncol = numFactors)
j <- 1
k <- 1
output <- list()
for (i in 1:(numARow/2)) { ##This wil create all possible 2 combinations in the style of 1&2,3&4...
  l <- (2*i) - 1  ## 1, 3, 5 ....
  first <- org[j,]
  if (k != j) {
    second <- org[k,]
    k <- k +1
  }
  if (k == j) {
    second <- org[k,]
    k <- k +1
  }
  output[[i]] <- rbind(first,second)
  if (k == (orgRow+1)) {
    j <- j + 1
    k <- j
        }
}
```